# Database of elastic constants

Tags: elastic-modulus

I'm interested in locating a database containing the elastic constants (the tensor matrix) for a variety of materials (preferably for a variety of symmetry classes). I don't have a particular material in mind, so just some general list would be very helpful. If someone knows of a good resource I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: a start for you  http://www.matweb.com/  .  Published, validated tensor constants are actually very hard to come by even for common materials.. best of luck